# Get pseudo-random item with given probability

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I want to give the user a prize when he signs in;
but it needs to be there some rare prizes so I want to appear prizes with different chances to appear using percents

i want to display one of these
`[50 : 'flower'], [30 : 'book'], [20 : 'mobile'];`
using percents they have

if there any way using Node.js or just javascript functions it would be great

Comment: u need to get more information on how your code looks like, and btw this list is invalid syntax..
also your question is too general u need to be more specific

Comment: Is the prize randomly chosen (with corresponding probability) or it's strict match or is it closest to the input value?

Comment: And you should adjust your input data to some valid notation (I guess, object would fit the best: `{50: 'flower', 30: 'book', 20: 'mobile'}`

Comment: yes the prize is randomly but with  different chances to appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*'Right off the top of my head'*-approach would be to prepare an array where each source item occurs the number of times that corresponds to respective probability and pick random item out of that array (assuming probability value has no more than 2 decimal places):

```js
// main function
const getPseudoRandom = items => {
  const {min, random} = Math,
        commonMultiplier = 100,
        itemBox = []
  for(item in items){
    for(let i = 0; i < items[item]*commonMultiplier; i++){
      const randomPosition = 0|random()*itemBox.length  
      itemBox.splice(randomPosition, 0, item)
    }
  }        
  return itemBox[0|random()*itemBox.length]
}

// test of random outcomes distribution
const outcomes = Array(1000)
        .fill()
        .map(_ => getPseudoRandom({'flower': 0.5, 'book': 0.3, 'mobile': 0.2})),
      
      distribution = outcomes.reduce((acc, item, _, s) => 
        (acc[item] = (acc[item]||0)+100/s.length, acc), {})

console.log(distribution)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

While above approach may seem easy to comprehend and deploy, you may consider another one - build up the sort of probability ranges of respective width and have your random value falling into one of those - the wider the range, the greater probability:

```js
const items = {'flower': 0.5, 'book': 0.2, 'mobile': 0.2, '1mUSD': 0.1},

      // main function
      getPseudoRandom = items => {
        let totalWeight = 0,
            ranges = [],
            rnd = Math.random()
        for(const itemName in items){      
          ranges.push({
            itemName,
            max: totalWeight += items[itemName]
          })
        }           
        return ranges
                .find(({max}) => max > rnd*totalWeight)
                .itemName
      },
      
      // test of random outcomes distribution
      outcomes = Array(1000)
        .fill()
        .map(_ => getPseudoRandom(items)),

      distribution = outcomes.reduce((acc, item, _, s) => 
        (acc[item] = (acc[item]||0)+100/s.length, acc), {})

console.log(distribution)
```

Comment: it give me a random but the chances doasn't work; i do `const probabilities = {1000: '0', 0.1: '3'},` and it still give me 3 very much

Comment: @rashidhacker : just missed one tiny detail, [got it working now as expected](https://codepen.io/ygorbunkov/pen/ZEWoEKM?editors=0012)

Comment: even if this really hard code; But thank you, its work !!!!

Comment: @rashidhacker : feel free to ask whatever confuses you, I'll gladly explain above code piece by piece

Comment: I want to know how to add 0.1 or 0.01 and the same values,  the function doesn't work with these numbers, that all what I need to know

Comment: @rashidhacker : as I had a bit more time to pay more effort, I have revised my answer to improve both performance and readability, addressing your *fractional probability concern* along the way. Check out the latest edit, hopefully it works for you.

Comment: thank you very much !! I solve the last problem just by add ( * 100 ) for any number to make it accept 0.01 ( because that the length I want) numbers and so, but your current function gives me a big lag to work. so I will use the last function, and you don't need to do anything more, because it works with me more than I expected, so thank you very much for tired with me!!!

Answer (score 4):

You can create a function to get weighted random results, something like this:

```js
const weightedSample = (items) => {
    // cache if necessary; in Chrome, seems to make little difference
    const total = Object.values(items).reduce((sum, weight) => sum + weight, 0)

    const rnd = Math.random() * total
    let accumulator = 0

    for (const [item, weight] of Object.entries(items)) {
        accumulator += weight

        if (rnd < accumulator) {
            return item
        }
    }
}

// check frequencies of each result

const prizes = { flower: 50, book: 30, mobile: 20 }
const results = Object.fromEntries(Object.keys(prizes).map(k => [k, 0]))

for (let i = 0; i < 1e6; ++i) {
    const prize = weightedSample(prizes)
    
    ++results[prize]
}

// sample results: { flower: 500287, book: 299478, mobile: 200235 }
console.log(results)
```

This will work regardless of whether the weights add up to 100, whether they're integers, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

"Certain probability" and "random" could lead to different approaches!

If you want random each time, something like:

```
let chances = [[0.2,'mobile'],[0.5,'book'],[1.0,'flower']]
let val = Math.random() // floating number from 0 to 1.0
let result = chances.find( c => c[0] <= val )[1]
```

This will give a random result each time. It could be possible to get 'mobile' 100 times in a row! Rare, of course, but a good random number generate will let that happen.

But perhaps you want to ensure that, in 100 results, you only hand out 20 mobiles, 30 books, and 50 flowers. Then you might want a "random array" for each user. Pre-fill the all the slots and remove them as they are used. Something like:

```
// when setting up a new user
let userArray = []
let chances = [[20,'mobile'],[30,'book'],[50,'flower']]
changes.forEach( c => {
  for(let i = 0; i < c[0]; i++) userArray.push(c[1])
})
// save userArray, which has exactly 100 values
// then, when picking a random value for a user, find an index in the current length
let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * userArray.length)
let result = userArray[index]
userArray.splice(index,1) // modify and save userArray for next login
if(userArray.length === 0) reinitializeUserArray()
```

There are different approaches to this, but just some ideas to get you started.

Comment: you're right! I forget the number. The idea is that when the user finishes the final chance item to reset all the chances (not implemented). Good catch.