# Returning values weighted according to some non-zero probability

Tags: javascript, function, probability

I'm trying to implement a function that returns some predefined values with a particular probability.

For people knowing Python's `NumPy` module, I suppose I'm wondering whether there is an equivalent to `numpy.random.choice()` in JavaScript?

If not, how else one could go about this efficiently?
Here my code:

```
    // outcomes
    const max_outcome = 10;
    const min_outcome = -10;
    let x1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max_outcome - min_outcome + 1) + min_outcome);
    let y1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max_outcome - min_outcome + 1) + min_outcome);

    // probabilities
    const max_proba = 1;
    const min_proba = 0.5;
    let p1 = Math.random() * (max_proba - min_proba) + min_proba;
    p1 = Math.round(p1 * 100) / 100;
    let p2 = 1 - p1;
    p2 = Math.round(p2 * 100) / 100;

  function return_value(x1, y1, p1, p2) {
     // should randomly return x1 with p1 probability or y1 or p2 probability}
```

Any ideas/thoughts would be gratefully received.

Comment: You could always get your feet wet in statistics. Or do a simple internet search on an equivalent library. But SO is not a code writing service, especially when this one definitely wheel reinvention.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get pseudo-random item with given probability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64010126/get-pseudo-random-item-with-given-probability)